# Add column as a result of an operation of another 2 already selected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT   `manager` AS manager,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `las-olas` where total_general>=0 and total_general<80 and manager=ol.manager and ola=ol.ola) as critical,
COUNT(1) as total
FROM `las-olas` ol
where zona="East" and ola=6
GROUP BY manager
order by critical DESC, manager
```

that brings me this result:

```
manager    critical    total
Critobal   9           25
Miguel     9           25
Cesar      8           37
Jesus      3           29
```

I want to have in the result table another column called "percent" that is the result of **`critical/total*100`** for each row:

```
manager    critical    total    percent
Critobal   9           25       36
Miguel     9           25       36
Cesar      8           37       22
Jesus      3           29       10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could surround that query with another select that does the calculation

```
select manager, critical, total, critical * 100/total from
            (SELECT   `manager` AS manager,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `las-olas` where total_general>=0 and
        total_general<80 and manager=ol.manager and ola=ol.ola) as critical,
     COUNT(1) as total
     FROM `las-olas` ol
     where zona="East" and ola=6
     GROUP BY manager
     order by critical DESC, manager) TotalCounts
```